# Migrate RAID 5 from USB

Tags: raid, nas, usb-3

My file server is dead, I think it's the motherboard.
I have a RAID 1 and a RAID 5 setup (Windows 8 software RAID) which I would like to migrate to a new Synology DS414.

I have an Intel NUC, is it possible to use SATA to USB cables and then recreate the RAIDs on the NUC so I can migrate to Synology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You RAID 1 volume should be able to be loaded into any external enclosure and read from. You also only need one of the disks, since they are simple mirrors of each other. After that just transfer the files over to your Synology.

the RAID5 could be trickier...
Like a RAID1, a RAID5 is simply 5 disks mirrored to each other. They all contain the same data, with the exception of the parity data which ensures the data is correct within the RAID set. Before anything, I would take the non-Parity disk and pop it into an external enclosure. with any luck, you will be able to read from it and you can move the files to your Synology.

If that doesn't work, things could be a bit more difficult:
AFAIK, if you are using Windows software RAID, the only thing that can utilize that particular type of RAID would be the Windows where it was created. In theory, if you connect all of your disks to your NUC in the same ports as your file server, the system 'should' boot up. This is one of the only upsides to using software RAID, that it is hardware independent(for the most part). USB adapters will not work for you in this case.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how you also had your disks configured within the controller. If you had them all attached as single volumes, and used Win8 to RAID them, the above method should work for you.

Worst case would be to find another mobo with the same disk controller as your old one and set it up so you can boot your old RAID, then shovel the data onto your new server.

Comment: Good point on the RAID1, that should work, I'll do that now :-)
Re the RAID5, it's only 3 disks, and AFAIK parity is stripped across them. I was hoping to connect them to the NUC using SATA to USB (2 of the disks should do the trick), that way I don't need to shop for a mobo.

Comment: Opps, for some reason I was thinking of a RAID4 when commenting on your RAID5. Most of the above still holds, but you 'might' be able to get away with externally mounting them. I don't think USB mounting will work though, since the NUC will view them as two independent disks rather than a single RAID volume.

Answer (score 0):

First, many times RAID 1's are readable without the RAID software or hardware.  So the RAID 1 should be readable with a direct connection to your NUC.

RAID 5 on the other hand is distributed parity and that leaves you needing the specific hardware or software that created the array to read the array.

With software RAID, the array should be able to be read by any iteration of the software that created the array.  That is, if you used windows 8 for the array, they you should be able to use any other windows 8 to read it.  On the flip side, nothing else will read it unless it is designed to read a window 8 array, which most things are not.

So load up or find another windows 8 computer, attach the disks how ever you have to, and go about remounting the old array.  This means you could load windows 8 on the NUC and attach the SATA disks and read the array.  The trick obviously being how attach 3 SATA drives to USB.  Using USB to SATA adapters should work, but might prove unreliable, or it might not work at all.

Another idea might be to find an old computer that you can load windows 8 on so you can directly connect the SATA drives to a mainboard.  Take the drive from the old file server or find another drive you can use, then use it to load a temporary system on a temporary computer (you'll have to probably reload windows, but maybe not).  Attach your drives, reclaim the array, make your transfer, then undo it all and put the other computer back to its original hardware state.

You are smart to use software RAID because it is easier to get the software back than the hardware.